# Open a file returns empty

Tags: python, file

I wanna open a file which is .java and contains "Application" in filename. The file is access correctly but I get a empty string when try read the file.

The file isn't empty and *application_class.tell()* returns 0 (what means that pointer read is in the start of the file). What I can do for read my file?

```
import os

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
filename_application = ""

for file in files:
    if "Application" in file:
        filename_application = file
application_class = open(filename_application, "r")
#application_class.seek(0)
print(application_class.tell())
print(application_class.read())
```

My directory

```
$ ls
CustomersApplication.java main.py
```

Comment: I think you need to change your indentation unless you expect only one application file per directory

Comment: I expect only one application file, this is the "main" of my Java project.

Comment: From testing it doesn't look like you can just read in a Java file

Comment: Java is camel case ("application" will exist only if is the wrong file) and I want read the "CustomersApplication.java" file, verify case sensitivity makes no sense in this scenario.

Comment: Are you getting proper file name in "filename_application" variable? is this file exist in current directory ?

Comment: filename_application returns "CustomersApplication.java" and my current directory contains "CustomersApplication.java" and "main.py" (my script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application_class.tell() returns the current position, which is correct.
Try changing the order of read() and tell().

Also, the program could be simplified:

```
import os

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and "Application" in f]

filename_application = files[0] if files else ""
if not filename_application:
    print "Application not found!"
else:
    application_class = open(filename_application, "r")
    print(application_class.read())
    print(application_class.tell())
```

Comment: My application_class.read() returns a empty string anyway :-(

Comment: Check what `open` returns. Also, try printing filename_application to ensure that this is the file you are after.

Answer (score 1):

To `tell()` size you need to `seek()` to end of file:

```
application_class.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
print(application_class.tell())
```